# Converting UTC time in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use an API in a practice project and one of the values in the JSON, `dateTimeLocal`, is a date & time in UTC format.

In my `cellForRowAt` method I put the date/time into a label:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventsCell", for: indexPath) as! EventsTableViewCell

    let event = eventData[indexPath.row]

    cell.eventTimeLabel.text = event.dateTimeLocal

    return cell
}
```

And this prints out the date and time as:

`2018-11-26T19:00:00`

I'd like to get this date and time in a format that reads, using the above date/time as an example,

`November 26, 2018 @ 7:00pm`

Is this possible or will I have to include the date and time in the given UTC format?

---

Here's the rest of the code if it's applicable to this issue:

The structs to decode the JSON:

```
struct Welcome: Decodable {
    let events: [Event]
}

struct Event: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let dateTimeLocal: String
    let venue: Venue

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case dateTimeLocal = "datetime_local"
        case venue
    }
}
```

And this function to fetch the data:

```
func fetchData<T: Decodable>(url: URL, completion: @escaping (FetchResult<T>) -> (Void)) {

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else {completion(.failure(error!)); return}

        do {
            let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            completion(.success(object))
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Which is called in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
    fetchData(url: seatGeekApiUrl) { (result: FetchResult<Welcome>) -> (Void) in

        switch result {
        case .success(let object): self.eventData = object.events
            print("\neventData: \n\n\(self.eventData)")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("\nError decoding JSON: \n\n\(error)")
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all decode `dateTimeLocal` as `Date`

```
let dateTimeLocal: Date
```

and add the appropriate date decoding strategy to decode the (not fully compliant) ISO 8601 string

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
let object = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
```

In the view controller class add a static date formatter on the top level

```
let dateFormatter : DateFormatter = {
   let formatter = DateFormatter()
   formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
   formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy '@' h:mma"
   return formatter
}()
```

and in `cellForRow` assign the formatted date

```
cell.eventTimeLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: event.dateTimeLocal)
```

Comment: Thanks vadian you're a huge help as always - the date decoding strategy that you suggest will go in the `do` portion of the `fetchData` function (thanks to you for help with that as well)? Or shall I make a separate function to handle the dates?

Comment: Just replace the single `decode` line in the `do` block with the 3 lines

Comment: Got it - I'm getting an error `dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "events", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "datetime_local", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected date string to be ISO8601-formatted.", underlyingError: nil))`. I'm not changing anything in my call to `fetchData` in `viewDidLoad` am I?

Comment: Darn, the string is not fully ISO8601 compliant (the trailing Z is missing). I updated the answer.

Comment: That did the trick! That `formatter` is really useful! I'll have to look into ISO8601, I'm not familiar with that at all. Thanks a million vadian, hope you're having a great weekend.